# How to disable auto data bind of ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

How can I prevent ASP.NET page from automatically binding data controls on the page? I want to increase performance and I want to do binding of each data control based on my own order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple, don't setup data binding on the controls in the designer.

You would then have to bind the controls inside the code behind part of the page with code.

Comment: So simple but really helped a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not quite what the OP asked for but it is also possible to cancel the Select operation on the Datasource control by adding an event handler to the Selecting event.

```
public void DataSource_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    if (CancelSelect())
    {
        e.Cancel=true;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good trick to stop the gridview loading the data, even with the DataSource="" set at design time. And like Tony said, just re-BIND it when you want in the code behind or button or anything else you want to trigger a data load.